# Select data from a column, by date, for a product, stdev and count function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a column of data sorted by date.  I want to perform product, stdev and count  functions on the data that is greater than my cut date.  I can do this by using an additional column to select the data I want to work on.

Is it possible to obtain the same result without using an additional column?

I am using Excel 2010

Thanks

The formual in D is `=IF(B7>cut_date, C7,"")`

```
column A  column B   column C  column D                  

cut_date  Product D   0.960
7/15/2014 Stdev D     0.018
          Count D         4

          Date       Value                                
          04/30/14   1.008                                
          05/30/14   1.002                                
          06/30/14   0.989                                
          07/31/14   1.013    1.013                       
          08/29/14   0.986    0.986                       
          09/29/14   0.992    0.992                       
          10/31/14   0.969    0.969
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to use array formulas with a similar syntax to your existing formula....but used on a range, e.g.

> =STDEV(IF(B7:B100>cut_date,C7:C100))

confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER so that you get curly brackets like { and } around the formula. You can replace STDEV with other functions using the same syntax, although for a count, if you just want a count of the dates greater than the cutoff you can use a simple COUNTIF

> =COUNTIF(B7:B100,">"&cut_date)

Answer (score -1):

You could use a conditional formatting which you can use to edit the cells based on a formula.

Start by selecting the cells you want to format
Home -> Conditional Formatting -> New Rule -> Use a formula to determine which cells to format -> Input Formula =B7>cut_date. This will format the cell if its true.